# how to remove '\"' from json format

Tags: python, json, dictionary, encode

when i print this

```
print(df['data'])
```

the output are:

```
{"form_code":"PREQUOTE-01","product":{"product...
```

but when i use df.to_json(orient='records')
the output are:

```
"data":"{\"form_code\":\"PREQUOTE-01\",\"product\":{\"product_code\":\"MV-CAR
```

how can i remove ' **\"** ' from my json, because i always fail when i load it

and this is the example when i finish dump it to json file format :

```
{"id": 4, "quotes_id": 4, "data": "{\"form_code\":\"PREQUOTE-01\",\"product\":{\"product_code\":\"MV-CAR-ASWATA-02\"...
```

can anyone help me, i want to the output like this :

```
{"id": 4, "quotes_id": 4, "data": "{'form_code':'PREQUOTE-01','product':{'product_code':'MV-CAR-ASWATA-02'...
```

thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are able to retrieve the value of the data in this key-value pair:

```
"data":"{\"form_code\":\"PREQUOTE-01\",\"product\":{\"product_code\":\"MV-CAR
```

You can use the following code snippet:

```
dataString = dataString.replace("\", "")
```

Then, all the "\" chars will be removed from the value of the data key.

Comment: this show me new error : 

datas = datas.replace('\', '') 
                                  ^
SyntaxError: EOL while scanning string literal

Comment: this is the correct format: datas = datas.replace('\", "")